# memory issue when removing an array from NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

My goal is to be able to update objects in NSUserDefaults.

This is my approach, and my concern is that when I replace the arrays using removeObjectForKey, is there any memory issue than can be created. The objects that were in the array are saved in objectArray by means of initWithArray:. oldSavedArray is the array with the previous contents of NSUserDefaults.

```
objectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldSavedArray];

if ([objectArray containsObject:myObject]){

            // remove the current object
            [objectArray removeObject:_currentFood];

            // reset our new array of objects
            [_defaults removeObjectForKey:@"mySavedData"];
            [_defaults setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:objectArray] forKey:@"mySavedData"];
        }
        else{ 

            // add the current object
            [objectArray addObject:_currentFood];                

            // reset our new array of favorite food
            [_defaults removeObjectForKey:@"mySavedData"];
            [_defaults setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:objectArray] forKey:@"mySaveData"];
        }
```

Comment: I think this is the source of my EXC_BAD_ACCESS error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question

> Is there any memory issue by using "removeObjectForKey"?.

My answer is No. But that step is not necessary.

```
[defaults setObject:forKey:]
```

is enough.

Comment: so setObject:forkey actually overwrites whatever object was saved under that key previously?

Comment: This answer is right, I assuming you are releasing the objectArray after you make the swap.

Comment: I do not release objectArray because it is initialized with autorelease, no? Doesn't initwithArray autorelease the array?

Comment: @derek.lo. initWithArray is just like any another method. It doesn do any memory allocation or pointing. the keyword here is 'alloc'.When you alloc or copy or retain or new something you are the owner of it. you must release it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:`.  You can simply pass in the array.  Also, `setObject` retains the item, so you should `release` your `objectArray` at the end.

Comment: I'm using a custom object so it needs to be encoded when entered into defaults and unarchived when loaded up. OK thanks for the tip!